# Completion Suggester in elastic search does not return results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having difficulties to make the Completion Suggester work in my code.

I'm trying to make an autocomplete component that will search previously run queries. I want to use the Completion Suggester.

I have the following mapping:

```
{
  "liferay-20116": {
    "mappings": {
      "querySuggestion": {      
        "properties": {
          "companyId": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "store": true
          },
          "keywordSearch_en": {
            "type": "string",
            "fields": {
              "ngram": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "gsearch_shingle_analyzer",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
              },
              "suggest": {
                "type": "completion",
                "analyzer": "simple",
                "payloads": false,
                "preserve_separators": true,
                "preserve_position_increments": true,
                "max_input_length": 50,
                "context": {
                  "company": {
                    "type": "category",
                    "path": "companyId",
                    "default": [
                      "20116"
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to run a suggestion on the *keywordSearch_en* field. I tried

```
POST liferay-20116/_suggest 
{
  "my-suggester": {
    "text": "service",
    "completion": {
      "field": "suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting only this error message: "Field [suggest] is not a completion suggest field".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong syntax for the _suggest.

the syntax should be something like this.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_suggest' -d '{
  "my-suggestion" : {
    "text" : "the amsterdma meetpu",
    "term" : {
      "field" : "body"
    }
  }
}'
```

you should have in mind _search is better than _suggest. as referenced [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-suggesters.html)

> To save some network overhead, filter out unnecessary fields from the
>   _source using source filtering to minimize _source size. Note that the _suggest endpoint doesn’t support source filtering but using suggest on the _search endpoint does

If you want to use your syntax which you
are using as of now. suggest should be used with _search endpoint and
use something like this.

```
POST music/_search
{
    "_source": "suggest", 
    "suggest": {
        "song-suggest" : {
            "completion" : {
                "field" : "suggest" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the nesting of the suggested field. The working body should be:

```
POST liferay-20116/_suggest 
{
  "my-suggester": {
    "text": "service",
    "completion": {
      "field": "keywordSearch_en.suggest"
    }
  }
}
```

The problem that I run into was also that I messed up my mappings with missed typed queries and then the field name became duplicated and the suggestions stopped work.